# jquery last added element

Tags: jquery

I am loading some HTML elements via jQuery:

Considder this case:

```
<li>test</li> (1)
<li>test</li> (2)
<li>test</li> (3)
```

If i do:

```
    $("body").find('li:last')
```

I will get the last li element, the one i marked (3) and if i was always sequentially adding items that would be fine. However if i add a new element in between:

```
<li>test</li> (1)
<li>test</li> (2)
<li>test</li> (4)<-
<li>test</li> (3)
```

:last wont do, because the element i added is not the last in the list.

How do i get a reference to (4)?

edit: and please, no eq() solutions, i need this to be dynamic and i can't always know where the element is added in the context.

Comment: That it was lastly added to the DOM, nothing more or less - index is not an option.

Comment: One option is to save indices of the loaded elements to some ordered list (i.e. in array) and pop the last.

Comment: jQuery does not have a built in function to detect changes/last changes?

Comment: @Eirinn How are you adding the new element?

Comment: Using underscoreJS for templating and BackboneJS for structure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add the last element you can try to add a class with:

```
.addClass("lastAdd");
```

And then you'll get the reference `$(".lastAdd")`

Comment: This could work - should use less resources than adding a new list and parsing through it...

Comment: But if you append multiple items with that method, I think the selector would then return ALL the items with that class, not just the last one added...

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in way to know what the last element added was. You'll have to keep track of it yourself.

There are a least a couple of ways to do that.

1. You could keep a reference to it in your code.
2. You could use a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) or a class and go looking for it later, e.g.:

   ```
   // Get the last
   var last = $("[data-last]");

   // When adding
   $("[data-last]").removeAttr("data-last"); // clear from previous
   $(....).append(...).attr("data-last", 1); // set on the new one
   ```

   or

   ```
   // Get the last
   var last = $(".last");

   // When adding
   $(".last").removeClass("last");       // clear from previous
   $(....).append(...).addClass("last"); // set on the new one
   ```
3. ***(Added)***: As there's only ever **one** "last" element, I think [Armen's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379983/157247) using an `id` makes sense, although not the way he did it. No need for a counter at all, just use `last`:

   ```
   // Get the last
   var list = $("#last");

   // When adding a new one
   $("#last").attr("id", "");
   $(...).append(...)[0].id = "last"; // Or .attr("id", "last");
   ```

I'd tend to prefer <s>#1</s>#3, but #1 and #2 has some real use cases.

Comment: Had to accept Cedrun's answer as he was first with a method that solved my problem. I've upvoted your solution though because all the methods mentioned here will also work.

Comment: @Eirinn: Yeah, I'd upvoted Cedrun as well (and Armen, I think `id` was reasonable if you're not using it for something else). Glad that sorted it for you.

Answer (score 2):

just add some attribute to your "li" element (e.g. id) and search by this attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

init new variable

```
var counter = 1;
```

after adding element increment counter

```
$('<li id=newli' + counter +'>test</li>').appendTo('body');
counter++;
```

and when you can to get that item, call:

```
var Id = $('#newli' + counter);
$(Id).
```

Comment: `id` values starting with digits are not valid in CSS (although they are in HTML5). Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, best not to use them when you're going to use jQuery to look them up. This approach also precludes having an `id` on the element for other reasons, and generates a **lot** of elements with `id`s (which get added to `window`). But that doesn't mean it's not a viable approach if you prefix the `id` with something.

Comment: $('<li id=newli' + counter +'>test</li>').appendTo('body');

var Id = $('#newli' + counter);

Comment: @ Armen: Exactly, +1. (You probably wanted the "edit" link there.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need jQuery to recall the elements you inserted in order, you have to add your own function (you might also change it but I don't recommend it...) :

```
var inserted = [];
$.fn.insertBeforeAndRecall = function(){
    inserted.push(this);
    this.insertBefore(arguments);   
}
function getLastInserted() {
    return inserted[inserted.length-1];
}
```

You use it by calling `insertBeforeAndRecall` instead of `insertBefore`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/bXbc5/)